# JQuery reveal modal on specific area, not freezing all background area

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, reveal.js

I'm newbie in JQuery, asking if i can reveal some modal but still can access some div.
because when i fire modal, the hole background become freezed and i want a specific div not freezed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
 $( "selector" ).dialog({
  modal:false
 });
```

when you use `modal:true` the background freezed.If it is false background not freezed.

try to use selector that is not covered your div.

Comment: what i meant that i want to access a specific div while modal is revealed

Comment: why you need to access specific div.may i knoe the reason

Comment: i think it is not possible for a specific div

Comment: i need to access div of the header so i can logout and access settings button while modal is revealed

Comment: then put that link in the dialog it self only.

Comment: i don't know what dialog ??

Comment: <a href = "#" data-reveal-id = "add-app-Modal">add app</a>
when i click this button, app-add-modal is revealed
i want to gain access on a specific div while that modal is revealed